# Select variable in multidimensional array or object with string - PHP

Tags: php, string, object, select, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have a variable in a multidimensional array or object like this:

```
$grid['rows'][0]['cols'][0]
```

And a string that looks identical:

```
"$grid['rows'][0]['cols'][0]"
```

Is there any way that could I use the string to select the above variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With eval.

```
$grid['rows'][0]['cols'][0] = 'bar';

$foo = '$grid[\'rows\'][0][\'cols\'][0]';

eval('$val_of_foo = '.$foo.';');
var_dump($val_of_foo); // string(3) "bar"
```

Comment: So simple. Thank you!